# What does Spinoza mean by Acquiescentia in se ipso?

Tags: ethics, metaphysics, history-of-philosophy, philosophy-of-religion, consciousness

In Part V of Spinoza’s *Ethics* the pinnacle of human freedom and understanding is discussed as the viewpoint from eternal blessedness. How are we to characterize or interpret this doctrine of intellectual love and unity with the divine? Does the idea of self disintegrate and melt into Nature as expressed in Spinoza’s metaphysical pantheism—as Schelling noted, assuming that one can be a witness to their own self-annihilation, which is impossible—or is this joy to be translated as glory or self-esteem and worth?

Essentially, how should we interpret Spinoza’s *acquiescentia* as the human mind *participating* in the intellect of God?